# Where can I create free symbol server for open source project?

Tags: c++, debug-symbols, symbol-server

My open source project it is C++ dynamic linking library. Most of bugs - crash.

I want create public symbol server to simplify debugging with memory dump.

See also: [Setting up a Symbol Server](http://entland.homelinux.com/blog/2006/07/06/setting-up-a-symbol-server/)

Comment: Well, if it's open source, why can't your users build the PDBs on their own?

Comment: @Alexander Gessler, because there are many versions of the library, it takes a long time to build the PDB files for old versions

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using Microsoft tools?  If so, all you should need to do is expose your 'symstore' directory with a web server then configure debuggers to access that store:

```
srv*symbol-cache-location*http://your.web.server.com/symboldir
```

The "Debugging Tools for Windows" docs (debugger.chm) has details for configuring IIS - I'm sure any other HTTP server will work just as well if you don't need authentication, which I imagine would be the case for an open source project. As far as I know, symsrv.dll just makes normal HTTP GET requests for symbol files when it's trying to get them from an HTTP server.

You'll also need to build the symbol store using the 'symstore' utility. Hopefully that can be integrated into your build or packaging process so it happens automatically.  Again, debugger.chm has good docs on the tool.

Comment: So, I just need to find a free Web server?

Comment: @KindDragon - I think so. Where's your project hosted - I think that project hosting services usually provide some web space, too.

Comment: CodePlex not provide web space

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a real answer, but you might want to take a moment to vote for C++ support in [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org) in work item [Support Managed C++ Project Types](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/868) or have a look at the discussion about [C++ Project support](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/280649). When that gets in, [SymbolSource](http://www.symbolsource.org) support will follow shortly (currently it only supports hosting symbols for .NET assemblies).